# How to fix number of blank rows in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am working on an issue where I needs to fix number of rows for a tablix. I am using a SQL query for the reporting service. My query returns 1-4 rows depending on the parameter passed.

I want to show blank rows in case the number of rows are less than 4.

Example: If the query returns 2 rows then I need to display 2 rows with data and other 2 blank rows.
Currently it displays only 2 rows. I am looking for a solution which displays blank rows as well

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can use CountRows("DATASETTITLE") together with outside rows of a table. Make 4 new rows and hide/show them depending the value returned from the function.

Comment: Instead of trying to make a fix on SSRS end, why don't you change the SQL dataset to always have 4 rows. There could be multiple methods to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Sourav It will be a good option if you can adjust the Rows in the Database query. But, if you have no control over it, then you can follow these steps:

```
1) After the data row insert four empty rows
2) Right click on first empty row and set visibility expression as 
 =IIF(CountRows("MyDataset") < 4 ,False ,True)
3) Right click on second empty row and set visibility expression as 
 =IIF(CountRows("MyDataset") < 3 ,False ,True)
4) Right click on third empty row and set visibility expression as 
 =IIF(CountRows("MyDataset") < 2 ,False ,True)
5) Right click on fourth empty row and set visibility expression as 
 =IIF(CountRows("MyDataset") < 1 ,False ,True)
```

If the query returns 0 rows from the database and if you don't want to show the empty rows then you no longer need the 4th row.

Here is more info on [CountRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156330%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) Funtion.